# AngularJS ui-select dropdown default value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select2

I am using [angular ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) for drop down. How can I set a default value for the drop down value?

```
<h3>Selectize theme</h3>
  <p>Selected: {{country.selected}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
      <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

The snippet is from [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview). Currently the dropdown just sowing default `Select or search a country in the list...` But i need to pass a value from controller. Lets say `$scope.default = {"name":"Decard"}`

### Thanks!!

### EDIT

This question is similar to [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983771/angularjs-ng-model-bind-from-json) but involving json return format of data.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can initial your ng-model to the default country object in your controller as following:

```
 $scope.country = {};
 $scope.country.selected = {name: 'Albania', code: 'AL'};
```

Then use "ui-select-match" to set the default value like this:

```
<ui-select ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">{{ $select.selected.name }}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
  <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
  <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
</ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: console giving out this error `Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined`

Comment: make sure u have defined the country in your controller before : $scope.country = {};

Comment: Ok, now the default is just empty.

Comment: Thanks.. I mistakenly set wrong variable name. Now it works

Comment: That's great.. Sure thing!

Comment: What if your ng-model is bound to the ID only, but the dropdown is an object ?

Comment: @PavanSandeep I don't now if this is the best solution, but you can use $filter to find the object with the desired ID (assuming the ID is a property of the object). Keep in mind that $filter returns an array, so if the ID is unique, just add [0] to the end of the filter definitions to get the first (and only) result.