# AngularJs ng-model bind from json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have following dropdown:

```
          <h3>Selectize theme</h3>
  <p>Selected: {{produk.category}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="produk.category" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match >{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="cat in categories | filter: $select.search">
      <span ng-bind-html="cat.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>

    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

In angular I get a data in json format:

```
   $scope.getProductToEdit = function(id){
      Account.getProductToEdit(id)
        .then(function(response){

            $scope.produk = response.data.product;

            //console.log($scope.produk); ---> return json
            return $scope.produk;
        })
        .catch(function(response){

        })
    }

if($stateParams.id){
    $scope.getProductToEdit($stateParams.id);
  }
```

In view I can't assign the json data to `ng-model="produk.category"` but it works for `<p>Selected: {{produk.category}}</p>`

This is what returned by json `Object {category: 'Tours'}`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are trying to read a property in your model that doesn't exist. Particularly in this line:

```
<ui-select-match >{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
```

From the code you have the value that is selected is `produk.category`. Inside there there is only the string `"Tours"`. And an string in Javascript has no property called name.

AngularJS normal behavior is to ignore when properties don't exist. So you get nothing. Changing it to this:

```
<ui-select-match >{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
```

will solve your problems (since now you are printing the string, not a non-existing property called `"name"` in your string).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $scope.getProductToEdit = function(id){
  Account.getProductToEdit(id)
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.produk = {}
        $scope.produk.category = response.data.product.category;

        //console.log($scope.produk); ---> return json
        return $scope.produk;
    })
    .catch(function(response){

    })
}
```